# Symbol of the San-colottes

Tags: french-revolution

I missed a section in Modern History and cannot find the answer to the question for a video that was shown in class.

The Topic was The Demise of King Louis.

Question: What is the symbol of the san-colottes.

Mind explaining what the san-colottes are? I couldn't understand the Wikipedia article that well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sans-Culottes](https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/rschwart/hist255/la/sans-culottes.html) were laborers and peasants and those aligned with them who were in opposition to the aristocracy. Their appellation comes from their distinctive outfit - long cotton pants commonly worn by laborers, as opposed to the knee-breeches ([culottes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culottes)) favored by the wealthy and hangers-on (to show off their expensive hosiery and shoes). In addition to their eponymous pants, they wore the short-skirted coat and wooden clogs also favored by commoners, and a "[red cap of liberty.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_cap#Revolutionary_icon)"

Comment: Just to clarify this answer. The "symbol" your teacher is asking about is the red cap.

Comment: Thanks for a more in depth answer. But, no the lecture was talking about the pants.

Answer (score -1):

I found a source trying to look up another question that I looked up that had the answer for this question. It is, that they refused to wear knee-pants.

Only to farther prove this is because the source had all the other questions relevant answers on the worksheet.